# Python won't run program

Tags: python, dijkstra

I'm new to python but have college experience in C# and Matlab. I am trying to write and run a dijkstras algorithm, but when I run it, nothing happens. I will attach the code (including commented out failed attempts) in hopes that someone can guide me in the right direction.

```
#must write script to turn matrix into this form of graph
graph = {'a':{'c':3,'e':5},'c':{'a':3,'d':5},'d':{'c':3,'e':6},'e':
{'d':6,'a':5}}
unseenNodes = {}
goal = {}
start = {}


#defining function
def dijkstra(graph, start, goal):
    shortest_distance = {} #empty dictionary
    predeccesor = {} #empty dictionary 
    unseenNodes = graph #makes it run through til all are seen
    path = []
def __init__(self):  
 #start node to next node
    print( str("hi"))

     for node in unseenNodes:
        shortest_distance[node]=9999999
        shortest_distance[start]=0
        print(shortest_distance)

#beefy bit of dijkstras alogrithim 
    while unseenNodes:
        minNode=None
        for node in unseenNodes:
            if minNode is None:
                minNode = node

            elif shortest_distance[node] < shortest_distance[minNode]:
                minNode = node

            for childNode, weight in graph [minNode].items():
                if weight + shortest_distance[minNode] < 
 shortest_distance[childNode]:
                    shortest_distance[childNode] = weight + shortest_distance[minNode]

                predeccesor[childNode] = minNode
                unseenNodes.pop(minNode)

                print(shortest_distance)

#reverse stack approach to trace path
    currentNode = goal
    while currentNode != start:
        try:
            path.insert(0,currentNode)
            currentNode = predeccesor[currentNode]
         except KeyError:
            print('path not valid')
        #break

        path.insert(0,start)
        if shortest_distance[goal] != infinity:
            #print(goal) 
            print('shortest distance is' + str(shortest_distance[goal]))
            print('path is' + str(path))
         else:
             Print('Something Went Wrong!')

#break

dijkstra(graph, 'a', 'd')
```

Comment: `__init__()` is never called. `__init__` in python is the class constructor (kinda), but these are all top level functions, you haven't put your `__init__` in a class. `dijkstra()` doesn't do anything, all it does is set some *local* variables which are destroyed on exit. Your indentation is also all wrong. I copied this into pycharm and got 32 errors! Can you post the fixed indented code please? -- all in all, I think you're getting a bit ahead of yourself and you need to take a step back.

Answer (score 2):

Your dijkstra function only carries out these four lines of code, as they are the only lines of code before you define a second function. So when you call this function at the end, the program creates some empty dictionaries and then closes:

```
shortest_distance = {} #empty dictionary
predeccesor = {} #empty dictionary 
unseenNodes = graph #makes it run through til all are seen
path = []
```

The second function you define, **init**() is a class method, you can't define it outside of a class.

Have a look at some more basic algorithms in python first, and familiarise yourself to the syntax (I don't know how different it is to C#).

Comment: Thanks. What would you recommend having a look at? I'm not to familiar with python having only started it two days ago

Comment: I personally used a tutorial called usingpython.com, that'll take you through the basic syntax. www.python-course.eu has a lot more in depth information about python itself which is useful. There's loads of free courses out there though, just try a few and see what you like.

Answer (score 0):

OK so I fixed up a bunch of your code's indentation, scoping and name issues (see below) and I got the following error

```
hi
{'a': 0}
{'a': 0, 'c': 9999999}
{'a': 0, 'c': 9999999, 'd': 9999999}
{'a': 0, 'c': 9999999, 'd': 9999999, 'e': 9999999}
{'a': 0, 'c': 3, 'd': 9999999, 'e': 9999999}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dijkstras.py", line 69, in <module>
    dijkstra(graph, 'a', 'd')
  File "dijkstras.py", line 47, in dijkstra
    unseen_nodes.pop(minNode)
KeyError: 'a'
```

Perhaps this will help you continue?

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# dijkstras.py

import math

# must write script to turn matrix into this form of graph
graph = {
    'a': {'c': 3, 'e': 5},
    'c': {'a': 3, 'd': 5},
    'd': {'c': 3, 'e': 6},
    'e': {'d': 6, 'a': 5}
}


# defining function
def dijkstra(graph, start, goal):
    shortest_distance = {}  # empty dictionary
    predeccesor = {}  # empty dictionary
    unseen_nodes = graph  # makes it run through til all are seen
    path = []

    # start node to next node
    print(str("hi"))

    for node in unseen_nodes:
        shortest_distance[node] = 9999999
        shortest_distance[start] = 0
        print(shortest_distance)

    # beefy bit of dijkstras alogrithim
    while unseen_nodes:
        min_node = None
        for node in unseen_nodes:
            if min_node is None:
                min_node = node

            elif shortest_distance[node] < shortest_distance[min_node]:
                min_node = node

            for childNode, weight in graph[min_node].items():
                if weight + shortest_distance[min_node] < shortest_distance[childNode]:
                    shortest_distance[childNode] = weight + shortest_distance[min_node]

                    predeccesor[childNode] = min_node
                    unseen_nodes.pop(min_node)

                    print(shortest_distance)

                    # reverse stack approach to trace path
    current_node = goal
    while current_node != start:
        try:
            path.insert(0, current_node)
            current_node = predeccesor[current_node]
        except KeyError:
            print('path not valid')
        # break

        path.insert(0, start)
        if shortest_distance[goal] != math.inf:
            # print(goal)
            print('shortest distance is' + str(shortest_distance[goal]))
            print('path is' + str(path))
        else:
            print('Something Went Wrong!')



if __name__ == '__main__':  # only run if script
    dijkstra(graph, 'a', 'd')
```

Comment: Appreciate it. Still in a rut but I will endeavour to carry on

Answer (score 0):

You need only one change

- Remove that `def __init__(self): function` from the code.
- the **__init__** function is used in **class** to initialize the the
  variables of object.
- You cant call `__init__` function thats why you were not getting any output.
- Also do proper *indentation* you will get your output.